# Is $l_p$ a closed subspace of $c_0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I would think it is, but I am not sure.

In an attempt trying to prove it, I take a series $(a_n)_m:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow l_p$, which is convergent in $c_0$. My goal is to show that $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}(a_n)_m=:a_n \in l_p \iff (\sum^\infty_{n=0}|a_n|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}<\infty$.

The convergence on $c_0$ means that for $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ $\exists N \,\, \forall k\in \mathbb{N}: $
$$\operatorname{sup}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|a_n-(a_n)_k|<\varepsilon$$.

I'm not sure how to go on. Can you help me, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question can be interpreted in two ways. Whether the id embedding $\ell_p \subset c_0$ is a closed subspace or whether we can abstractly embed $\ell_p$ inside some $c_0$ (posibly non-separable)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what that means to be honest. So what I meant was this: If we take $(c_0, || \, ||_{\operatorname{sup}})$ as a normed space, then obviously $l_p$ is not only a subset of it, but a subspace and I was wondering if that is closed? 
But now that you mentioned it. Is it possible to embed $l_p$ into $c_0$ with a homeomorphism $f$, such that $f(l_p)$ is closed? I have not yet learned about embeddings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $a=(k^{-1/p})_k$ and
$$
a^n=(1,2^{-1/p},\dots,n^{-1/p},0,0,0,\dots).
$$
Then $a^n$ converges to $a$ in $c_0$, but $a\notin\ell^p$.